# PLSQL : Assign a value(number) to all rows of a column, within a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table, that is something like this :

```
Invc_Ref | OrderID
(null)   | 123
(null)   | 124
(null)   | 125
(null)   | 126
```

I want to completely fill the Invc_Ref column with a certain value. Say 456789.

```
Invc_Ref | OrderID
456789   | 123
456789   | 124
456789   | 125
456789   | 126
```

I have nearly 200,000 in the table.

Comment: `update the_table set invc_ref = 456789`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
update your_table set invc_ref = 456789;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create such a simple procedure

```
SQL> create or replace procedure pr_invoices( i_invc_ref t_invoices.invc_ref%type ) is
begin
  update t_invoices
     set invc_ref = i_invc_ref;
end;
/
SQL> exec pr_invoices(456789);
```

and change the above scalar value whenever needed another.

***Caution :*** make sure there's no such procedure named as `pr_invoices` before, because of `replace` option used for the creating the procedure.

Comment: @Rene Since OP tells `within a procedure` in the title.